# Ajax call not happening with no errors passing multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call which is passing 4 parameters through JQUERY. It's not happening, neither giving any `error. onsuccess` with output values. I want to fill 2 textbox values like below.

ClientSide :

function doCalculation() {

```
        var obj = {};
        obj.apple = $("#ddlapple :selected").text();
        obj.banana = $("#ddlbanana :selected").text();
        obj.chocolate = parseFloat($("#txtchocolate").val().toString()).toFixed(2);
        obj.doll = parseFloat($("#txtdoll").val().toString()).toFixed(2);

        if (obj.chocolate > 0 && obj.doll > 0) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx/Calculation",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

On success I want to fill two textbox values with output params like below

```
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        var outputparams = response.d;
        $("#txtbox1").val(outputparams.abc);
        $("#txtbox2").val(outputparams.xyz)
    }
```

VB.NET code :

_
    Public Shared Function Calculation(ByVal apple As String, ByVal banana As String, ByVal chocolate As Decimal, ByVal doll  As Decimal) As ClassParams

{

// some calculation here

}

Public Class ClassParams

```
Public Property abc() As Decimal
Public Property xyz() As Decimal
```

End Class

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting answer for other people in future. I used many ways but only this one worked for me.

```
function doCalculation() {
var obj = {};
        obj.apple = $("#ddlapple :selected").text();
        obj.banana = $("#ddlbanana :selected").text();
        obj.chocolate = parseFloat($("#txtchocolate").val().toString()).toFixed(2);
        obj.doll = parseFloat($("#txtdoll").val().toString()).toFixed(2);

        if (obj.chocolate > 0 && obj.doll > 0) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx/Calculation",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"apple":"' + obj.apple + '","banana":"' + obj.banana + '","chocolate ":"' + obj.chocolate + '","doll":"' + obj.doll + '"}',
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    }




function OnSuccess(response) {
        var outputparams = response.d;
        $("#txtbox1").val(outputparams.abc);
        $("#txtbox2").val(outputparams.xyz)
    }
```

VB.NET Code:

Returning output params as class object and consuming that at clientside in Jquery to fill the textboxes with that value

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _

Public Shared Function Calculation(ByVal apple As String, ByVal banana As String, ByVal chocolate As Decimal, ByVal doll As Decimal) As ClassParams

{

     // some calculation here

}

Public Class ClassParams

Public Property abc() As Decimal
Public Property xyz() As Decimal

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option as 'failure' in jquery ajax. Replace failure with 'error' and check.

Comment: Ok. Let me check that . Moreover i changed the way of passing parameter like below    data: JSON.stringify({ apple:  obj.apple, banana : obj.banana , chocolate: obj.chocolate, doll: obj.doll}),

Comment: Looks like call is not reaching the server . Or response is not sent from the server for particular request. Debug your back end code.

Comment: I have corrected it by just changing the way of passing parameters like below :    data: '{"apple":"' + obj.apple + '","banana":"' + obj.banana + '","chocolate ":"' + obj.chocolate + '","doll":"' + obj.doll + '"}',                              .........  instead of any other way i tried. And checked many articles but this one only worked perfectly. ...  Thanks a lot Pradeep for all your effort and  time.